# God talking to Satan in the Book of Job,how did they know?

Tags: job-iyov-book-of, satan

Job chapter 1 vers 6 - 12

Talks about God and Satan having a conversation.Where does that story come from?
Job does not know what is going on and I have never heard anyone talk about it.
Is it a revelation or is it a tradition that helps us understand what was said in this conversation?
Who knew and who was told that this conversation was going on?

Does the Talmud talk about  this question?

Comment: See also https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/29305

Comment: See also also https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/90072

Answer (score 5):

Rambam writes in [Moreh Nevuchim](https://www.sefaria.org/Guide_for_the_Perplexed,_Part_2.45.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) ("Guide to the Perplexed), 2:45, that the Ketuvim, Writing, which **includes** the book of Job, that they were written under the inspiration of the holy spirit.

> (2) The second degree is this: A person feels as if something came upon him, and as if he had received a new power that encourages him to speak. He treats of science, or composes hymns, exhorts his fellow-men, discusses political and theological problems; all this he does while awake, and in the full possession of his senses. Such a person is said to speak by the holy spirit. David composed the Psalms, and Solomon the Book of Proverbs, Ecclesiastes, and the Song of Solomon by this spirit; **also Daniel, Job, Chronicles, and the rest of the Hagiographa were written in this holy spirit**; therefore they are called ketubim (Writings, or Written), i.e., written by men inspired by the holy spirit.

Therefore, the author, being divinely inspired, possessing *ruach hakodesh*, would know of these events.

Answer (score 0):

The Megillas Esther says (4,1 explained by Rashi)  that Mordechai knew about Hamans plot to kill all the Jews through a prophecy  in a dream even though he wasn't there when it happened. The *paytan* Rav Menachem ben Machir (11th century) of the *Selichos* on *Taanis Ester* "Adom Bekum Aleinu" quotes in the 5th paragraph that the Satan sat among the accusers to seal the verdict to destroy the people of Israel *Chas veshalom*.

So we see that *Nevua* (prophecy) can relate to the unseen of normal people.

Since the author of sefer Iyov  was  Moshe as mentioned Bava Basra 15a He probably also had a revelation before he wrote Iyov. It is also possible that Elihu who might be  a descendent of Yehuda from the family of Ram and prophesied for the gentiles (Bava basra, 15b) or he might be Yitzchok  Avinu (Yerushalmi Sotah 5,8) who was a Prophet (Rashi  Megilla 14a) authored Sefer Iyov. This makes sense  Since Elihu was the only person in the story who could reveal the true meaning of Iyovs suffering at the end of the Book so he with his superior prophecy (the others were also prophets but could not fully understand the yissurim)  wrote Sefer Iyov and could have had a dream about Hashem and the Satan but didn't reach the others till much later after all their discussions. The prophecy of Hashem with the Satan could have coming in a dream would be   just like Yaakov who had a dream of Hashem's revelation  and the Malachim  going up and down the ladder.

Comment: Mordechai's dreaming is a very old tradition https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Book_of_Esther#Additions_to_Esther

Answer (score -1):

The conversation between God and Satan is discussed by the Talmud at length in Bava Basra 15b-16a.

[Soncino Translation](https://halakhah.com/pdf/nezikin/Baba_Bathra.pdf):

> Now there was a day when the sons of God came to present themselves
>   before the Lord, and Satan came also among them. And the Lord said
>   unto Satan, whence comest thou? And Satan answered etc. He addressed
>   the Holy One, blessed be He thus: Sovereign of the Universe, I have
>   traversed the whole world and found none so faithful as thy servant
>   Abraham. For Thou didst say to him, Arise, walk through the land to
>   the length and the breadth of it, for to thee I will give it, and even
>   so, when he was unable to find any place in which to bury Sarah until
>   he bought one for four hundred shekels of silver, he did not complain
>   against thy ways. Then the Lord said to Satan, Hast thou considered my
>   servant Job? for’ there is none like him in the earth etc.
>
> Said R. Johanan: Greater praise is accorded to Job than to Abraham.
>   For of Abraham it is written, For now I know that thou fearest God,
>   whereas of Job it is written, That man was perfect and upright and one
>   that feared God and eschewed evil. What is the meaning of ‘eschewed
>   evil’? — R. Abba b. Samuel said: Job was liberal with his money.
>   Ordinarily, if a man owes half a prutah [to a workman], he spends it
>   in a shop, but Job used to make a present of it [to the workman].
>
> And then Satan answered the Lord and said, Doth Job fear God for
>   nought? Hast thou not made at hedge about him and about his house etc.
>   What is the meaning of the words, Thou hast blessed the work of his
>   hands? — R. Samuel b. R. Isaac said: Whoever took a prutah from Job
>   had luck with it. What is implied by the words, His cattle is
>   increased in the land, — R. Jose b. Hanina said: The cattle of Job
>   broke through the general rule. Normally wolves kill goats, but in the
>   cattle of Job the goats killed the wolves. But put forth thine hand
>   now and touch all that he hath, and he will renounce thee to thy
>   face... And the Lord said unto Satan, Behold all that he hath is in
>   thy power, only upon himself put not forth thine hand etc. . . . And
>   it fell on a day when his sons and daughters were eating and drinking
>   wine in their eldest brother's house that there came a messenger unto
>   Job and said, The oxen were plowing etc. What is meant by the words,
>   The oxen were plowing and the asses feeding beside them? — R. Johanan
>   said: This indicates that the Holy One, blessed be He, gave to Job a
>   taste of the future world. While he was yet speaking there came also
>   another and said, The fire of God. . . While he was yet speaking there
>   came also another and said, The Chaldeans made three bands . . . and
>   fell upon the camels and have taken them away . . . While he was yet
>   speaking there came also another and said, Thy sons and thy daughters
>   were eating and drinking wine in their eldest brother's house, and
>   behold there came a great wind from the wilderness and smote the four
>   corners of the house and it fell upon the young men . . . Then Job
>   arose and rent his mantle and shaved his head. . . and he said, Naked
>   came I out of my mother's womb and naked shall I return thither; the
>   Lord gave and the Lord hath taken away; blessed be the name of the
>   Lord. In all this Job sinned not nor charged God with foolishness.
>   Again there was a day when the sons of God came to present themselves
>   . . . and the Lord said unto Satan, From whence comest thou? And Satan
>   answered the Lord and said, From going to and fro in the earth etc. He
>   said: Sovereign of the Universe, I have traversed the whole earth, and
>   have not found one like thy servant Abraham. For thou didst say to
>   him, Arise, walk through the land in the length of it and the breadth
>   of it, for to thee I will give it, and when he wanted to bury Sarah he
>   could not find a place in which to bury her, and yet he did not
>   complain against thy ways. Then the Lord said unto Satan, Hast thou
>   considered my servant Job, for there is none like him in the earth . .
>   . and he still holdeth fast his integrity, although thou movedst me
>   against him to destroy him without cause. Said R. Johanan: Were it not
>   expressly stated in the Scripture, we would not dare to say it. [God
>   is made to appear] like a man who allows himself to be persuaded
>   against his better judgment. A Tanna taught: [Satan] comes down to
>   earth and seduces, then ascends to heaven and awakens wrath;
>   permission is granted to him and he takes away the soul.   And Satan
>   answered the Lord and said, Skin for skin, yea, all that a man hath
>   will he give for his life. But put forth thine hand now and touch his
>   bone and his flesh, and he will renounce thee to thy face. And the
>   Lord said unto Satan, Behold he is in thine hand: only spare his life.
>   So Satan went forth from the presence of the Lord and smote Job etc.
>   R. Isaac said: Satan's torment was worse than that of Job; he was like
>   a servant who is told by his master, ‘Break the cask but do not let
>   any of the wine spill.’ Resh Lakish said: Satan, the evil prompter,
>   and the Angel of Death are all one. He is called Satan, as it is
>   written, And Satan went forth from the presence of the Lord. He is
>   called the evil prompter: [we know this because] it is written in
>   another place, [Every imagination of the thoughts of his heart] was
>   only evil continually, and it is written here [in connection with
>   Satan] ‘Only upon himself put not forth thine hand. The same is also
>   the Angel of Death, since it says, Only spare his life, which shows
>   that Job's life belonged to him.
>
> R. Levi said: Both Satan and Peninah had a pious purpose [in acting as
>   adversaries]. Satan, when he saw God inclined to favour Job said, Far
>   be it that God should forget the love of Abraham. Of Peninah it is
>   written, And her rival provoked her sore for to make her fret. When R.
>   Aha b. Jacob gave this exposition in Papunia, Satan came and kissed
>   his feet.

Comment: Thank you But it does not answer the question.How they knew.. Did a prophet have a revelation and see the conversation Or is there a tradition maybe like The feasts ,Maybe the  angels comes before Hashem and talks with him during one of the feasts every year ?This is Before Moses but the times was before Moses.

Comment: @Northlight2018 How did who know? The Talmud? The author of Job?

Comment: There is a conversation God has with Satan.Where did the knowledge come from that this conversation did tak place?

Comment: @Northlight2018 That is a question you can ask on hundreds of stories. For some of them, the Sages probably had traditions, for some they expounded based on textual anomalies, some might have just been meant to convey a particular message regardless of historical accuracy, etc. But the Talmud does attempt to prove that Megillas Esther was written with Divine Inspiration based on assertions that could otherwise not have been known.

Comment: @Northlight2018 Remember also that the Talmud ascribes authorship of Job to Moses – it is not surprising that the greatest prophet would know this. Additionally, one Talmudic opinion holds that Job is a fiction.

Comment: Moses would know alot,then how did he know ?Would be the question,so the question still remains.

Comment: @Northlight2018 Moses only went to Heaven to receive the Torah, it's not so far-fetched...