# Proof of Divine Inspiration in Megillas Esther

Tags: megillat-esther, tractate-megillah, ruach-hakodesh

The Talmud (Megillah 7a) tries to prove that Megillas Esther was composed with Divine Inspiration:

> It has been taught: R. Eleazar said: Esther was composed under the
>   inspiration of the holy spirit, as it says, And Haman said in his
>   heart.

This is referring to the part of the story where Haman paid the king a late night visit:

> So Haman came in. And the king said to him, What shall be done to the
>   man whom the king delights to honor? Now Haman thought in his heart,
>   To whom would the king delight to do honor more than to myself?

The proof seems to that the authors could not have known what Haman thought in his heart without Divine Inspiration. But even ignoring Haman's internal thoughts, how would the authors have known the conversation that took place in the kings private chambers? Is there any evidence that someone told them the contents of the conversation? If not, shouldn't this itself be the proof of Divine Inspiration?

Comment: Is it not in the talmud walls(or birds) have ears,

Comment: @hazoriz Your point being?

Comment: @ezra evidence that there is not such a thing as private conversations, (another idea can be that a king usually has servants with him even in his private chambers)

Comment: @hazoriz Berachos 8b, and Rashi there who cites Vayikra Rabba "אזנים לכותל".

Comment: @hazoriz Is there any source that that's what happened here?

Comment: @Alex I do not know, but why do you think it did not? (if you are using something as proof should it not be fullproof?)(For a bird of the sky shall carry the sound, and that which has wings shall tell the matter”(Ecclesiastes 10:20). https://www.sefaria.org/Bava_Batra.4a.2 )

Comment: @hazoriz Another thing is, would they rely on hearsay for something like this?

Comment: @Alex what you say makes sense, but if such a thing is possible , then it can not be used as proof of Divine Inspiration

Comment: @hazoriz Fair enough, although the Gemara does end up offering a rejection of this proof, that they could have "guessed" what Haman was thinking.

Comment: @Alex they could not, similar to the meraglim who could not have guessed how they looked like if not hearing it for themselves

Comment: @Alex (it is possible that when a king (not a privet person) has visitors it is known)

Answer (score 2):

the megilla says …..
after haman came home he said to
all his friends and zeresh…
את כל אשר קרהו

so haman himself announced to all
what occurred, so that was “public knowledge “

Answer (score 1):

Absence of evidence is not positive proof. The better proof is from the record of what went on in Haman's mind.